# Garage door torsion spring popping and warping. Tension or defect?

Tags: garage-door

### Background

A day or so after the garage door, track and torsion spring were professionally replaced, popping sounds are heard from the torsion spring during operation. This sound is emitted when the spring "pops" back into place after warping/ bending.

It occurs opening and closing when the garage door is closest to shut. Other than this issue, it seems to operate normally.

[image: torsion spring warping]
[image: torsion spring close-up]
[image: torsion bar and spring]

### Question

Is this behavior typical, or a result of something like the tension requiring adjustment, or maybe a defective spring? While we are waiting to contact the installer (holiday weekend), is there any risk of it worsening if it continues to be used in the meantime?

Thank you.

Comment: aren't you supposed to oil those?

Comment: @JoePhillips I would think so. Especially professionally installed. I added a couple photos of the torsion spring itself for clarity.

Comment: If you have the instructions it should say how many turns and at what distance apart the ends of the springs are. You can measure and count to make sure it's correct

Comment: I have seen these blow! Use extreme caution if you try doing any adjustments. I would wait on the service person if it failed in a few weeks it was faulty in the first place.

Comment: The warpage is somewhat normal. The noise isn't. It's probably not a defective spring. Could be that it was installed with too little play in the coils, causing binding. I'd use the door as little as possible and get the installer back to fix it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the technician, the coil snaking is normal for new springs. It will become less pronounced as it "wears in." A bit more lubrication was applied and the binding has stopped.